# How can i use display flex in windows live mail app and the outlook app?

Tags: css, email, outlook, flexbox, display

How can i use display flex in the windows live mail app and the outlook app without using td's ?. I have tried using td's and it works but its destroying the looks of other mail clients like gmail and yahoo and even the outlook webversion.

Comment: (1) Infiltrate Microsoft (2) Make Outlook good are handling HTML (3) Wait for a significant portion of the population to upgrade to the new version

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way outlook works this is not currently possible. It uses an older version of HTML